# Is there something in Java (8) similar to "let" or "where" in Haskell

Tags: java

Though working, that seams a bit to much. Preventing the declaration of the *set* in the scope of *distinct* when creating a distinct list.

```
List<String> distinct = new ArrayList<>( ((Supplier<Set<String>>) () -> {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            for (D d : aHierarchicClassStructure) for (T t : d) for (U u : t)
                set.addAll(u.getSomething());
            return set;
        }).get());
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what are you trying to achieve? (input and expected output?)

Comment: No, there is no such thing. As you realized, the anonymous class is capable for similar functionality, though the answer from ekaerovets suggests it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> distinct = aHierarchicClassStructure.stream()
                                                 .flatMap((t) -> t.stream())
                                                 .flatMap((u) -> u.stream())
                                                 .distinct()
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You can use method reference, so `(t) -> t.stream` will become `Collection::stream()` or `List::stream()` if your data structure is List.

Comment: Probably it should just be `Collection::stream` or `Arrays::stream` instead of `t -> t.stream`.

Comment: @fabian I tend to use the actual type of the collection (e.g. List::stream()), which is unknown here. Collection::stream() is very good as well.

Comment: This works great. I tried before `.map(List::stream).reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat)` which produced a stack overflow.